# Attempting to create an object of type 'Item' with an existing primary key value '1'

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have three classes, `Folder`, `Object` & `Item`.

For every `Folder` there are a list of `objects`, and for every `Object` there should be a list of `items`. However when creating an `Object` with a default list of `items` I am getting the following error;

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Attempting to create an object of type 'Item' with an existing
>   primary key value '1'.'

For each class I have a function that counts all the objects and increments the ID, this works fine but there must be something wrong with how I am adding `Item` to an `Object.items` list property.

**Item**

```
class Item: Object {

@objc dynamic var id: Int = 0
@objc dynamic var object: Object?

@objc dynamic var title: String = ""

override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "id"
}

func IncrementaID() -> Int{
    let realm = try! Realm()

    var num = 1

    let allItems = realm.objects(Milestone.self)
    if allItems.count >= 1 {
        num = allItems.count + 1
    }

    return num
}


}
```

When creating an `Object` I am also trying creates `Item`'s to append to the objects `items` property like so

```
 func addObjectToFolder(_ title: String, folder: Folder) {


    let object = Object()

    object = object.IncrementaID()

    object.title = title


    let defaultList = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]

    for i in defaultList {

        let item = Item()

        item.id = item.IncrementaID()

        item.title = i

        object.items.append(item)
    }

    try! realm.write {
        folder.objects.append(object)
    }

}
```

Does an body know how I am going wrong when creating the default values for the `Objects.items` list ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value returned by your `IncrementaID` function only changes when the number of `Milestone` objects stored in your Realm changes. Your code contains a loop that creates multiple `Item` instances and initialized their `id` property to the value returned by `IncrementaID`. No `Milestone` objects are created or stored in the Realm between calls, so all of the `Item` objects end up with the same ID.

My suggestion: use the string representation of a UUID for your primary key, rather than trying to manage unique integers like this.

Comment: Yeah you're right, there is no need to manage the id's manually when UUID can be used, and is most likely more reliable